# How to use LAD RAD with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, document

I have done multiple research one how to implement LAD RAD on a springBoot application , but i have found nothing helpful yet that can help me understand how to use it .

Does someone have a any tutoriel or documentation that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Include the LAD or RAD agent jar file as a dependency in your Spring Boot project. You can download the agent jar file from the relevant website, or use a dependency management tool such as Maven or Gradle to manage the dependency.

Configure your application to use the LAD or RAD agent. You can do this by adding the following JVM arguments to your application startup command:

For LAD: -javaagent:/path/to/lad-agent.jar

For RAD: -javaagent:/path/to/rad-agent.jar

If you are using LAD, you will also need to add the following dependencies to your project's build file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you have configured your application to use the LAD or RAD agent, you can start using it to dynamically manipulate your application's bytecode. For example, you could use it to inject logging or tracing code into your application's methods.

It's worth noting that dynamic bytecode manipulation can have performance implications, so it's important to test your application thoroughly after enabling LAD or RAD to ensure that it is still performing well.